# Ajax read value of variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please take a look at these codes:

```
$.ajax( {
      url: 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/mp3?per_page=1&_embed',
      success: function ( data ) {
        var post = data[0];
        $postid =  post.id;
.
.
.
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=' + $postid,
```

When I open the page, in the console I see this line:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=undefined
```

Please tell me why it says $postid is undefined and how can I add the value of the $postid at the end of the second url.

Comment: Either `$postid` is not global, or your 2nd bit of code is running before the first has finished (as it's *asynchronous*)

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m the answer was there